# How many times is this nested while loop going to run?

Tags: loops, time-complexity

I'm having trouble with this one, I know the inner loop will run log(n) in base 6. But the outer loop troubles me.

```
i=n
while i>2
   j=1
   while j<i
      j=j*2
      i=i/3
```

Answer (score 1):

The analysis is actually not as hard as you may think. Note that every time the inner loop is executed, the value of `i` decreases to a third of it. Hence for the entire loop to reach the exit condition `i<=2`, the inner loop needs to run `\theta(log3(n))` times in total. That is the time complexity of the program. It is unnecessary to separately analyze how many times the outer loop runs and how many times the inner runs within each outer loop execution.

Comment: what do you mean "That is the complexity of the program"? the complexity of program does not depend on the outer loop only

Comment: I mean "time complexity". In this problem, the total number of inner loop executions is the dominant factor and you only need to count that to get the time complexity. And note that `log3(n)` is NOT the amount of outer loop executions but only a loose upper bound of that.

Comment: shouldn't it be a multiplication of the two? `\theta(log3(n)*log6(n)) = \theta(logn)^2` ?

Comment: @sadElephent No. \theta(log3(n)) is the TOTAL number of INNER loop executions, not OUTER loop executions. The outer loop executes far fewer times than log3(n). The value of `i` does NOT decrease to only `i/3` every OUTER loop. It is decreased to `i/3^log6(i)=i^log6(2)`.

Comment: If you think the answer is helpful, consider upvote it / mark it as the answer.